# How do I make one data frame to keep the same rows as another one?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have one data frame (df) x,

```
   A   B 
O  2   3
1  4   4
3  2   1
```

You may notice that the number 2 row is missing. That is because i have used x.dropna() and therefore the no.2 row is dropped as it is NAN.

Now I have another df y:

```
   C   D 
O  1   2
1  4   3
2  3   5
3  1   4
```

I want y to keep the same rows as x. That is, I want the no.2 of y to be removed.

I used following codes:

```
temp=x.join(y)
x=temp.ix[:,0:2]
y=temp.ix[:,2:4]
```

This would work. but I suppose there might be more direct way to do it?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use loc:

```
y.loc[x.index]
Out: 
   C  D
O  1  2
1  4  3
3  1  4
```

You can assign it back to y: `y = y.loc[x.index]`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.isin.html) to check if each index value of `y` is found in index value of `x`.

```
In [3]: y = y[y.index.isin(x.index)]

In [4]: y
Out[4]: 
       C  D
    O  1  2
    1  4  3
    3  1  4
```

Comment: Just a small caveat: this method is not equivalent to @ayhan's. It may produce different results if indexes are unsorted or contain duplicates.